# mysql workbench does not start after installing "export-laravel-5-migrations.py" plugin

Tags: laravel, plugins, workbench

Just installed mysql-workbench-community-8.0.25-winx64.msi on windows 10.

Works fine until I install 'export-laravel-5-migrations.py'
following: https://laravel-news.com/export-from-mysql-workbench-to-a-laravel-migration
I install the plugin, and close workbench, to restart..

After closing Workbench, it will not start anymore.

Event Viewer shows log:

```
Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 8.0.25.0, time stamp: 0x6089097e
Faulting module name: python37.dll, version: 3.7.7150.1013, time stamp: 0x5f8050b5
```

Solution seems to be to delete c:/user/../AppData/Roaming/MySQL/Workbench

That makes Workbench start again.
But then also plugin is gone...

Answer (score -1):

We install the plugin HTMLShemaReport.py which is also a Phyton file. Same result, it won't open Workbench even if you restart everything.

Solution is just to delete the folder Workbench. The directory is: %appdata%/MySQL/Workbench